# Delete folder on extension update

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, one-click-updates

I've created a script.php which contains the following function:

```
protected function update400()
{
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

    JFolder::delete(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/mod_MYMODULE/js');
}
```

This function is then called inside Joomla's predefined `preflight()`. The function is getting, called, however upon installation, I get the following error:

```
JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\wamp\www\tmp\install_53de639f7a0b6\400\media\js
```

At first I thought this was because I was calling `update400()` from the `preflight()` function, so I tried calling it from the `postflight()` function instead, however this did not make any difference.

What I'm trying to figure out, is why it's looking in the `tmp` folder when I have specifically defined the path.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `JPATH_SITE` within the update method which works fine for me.

I wouldn't use the `preflight` at all. It would delete the files even if the update fails, which is likely not what you want. `postflight` is the most appropriate but you need to check if it's an install, update or discover there.

Comment: I've tried calling it from the `postflight` function again and using `JPATH_SITE` instead of `JPATH_ROOT`, as suggested, but it did not make any difference. I'm already checking to see if it's an update and the function is only called if it is

Comment: I just put `JFolder::delete(JPATH_ROOT . '/media/mod_MYMODULE/js');` into my components postflight method and it tried to delete the correct folder.

No clue why it doesn't work for you, sorry :(

Comment: Hmm odd. I will some some more testing then. I'll be sure to test on a live host just in case it's something to do with my localhost dev environment

Comment: I've done some more testing. Tried using `_ROOT`, `_SITE` and  `_BASE` but none work. Also tried in Joomla 2.5 and 3.2 but the same issue occurs. Would you be able to provide your working example? This is assuming the folder/file to delete is in Joomla's **media** folder. You don't think this is a security measure that was implemented into Joomla to prevent any core files being deleted do you?

Comment: When I tested it, I did with my component (https://github.com/Bakual/SermonSpeaker/tree/master/com_sermonspeaker) and copied the command into my script.php.
It generated obviously the error that the folder doesn't exist (because it doesn't), but showed the correct path.

Comment: I think I see what's going on here. `JPATH_*` gets the path for the current application. There are constants for the administrator, components, plugin, libraries and other folder, however there **isn't** a constant for the *media* or *modules* folder. Someone else is also looking into this so I'll post any updates

Comment: `JPATH_ROOT` should always be the root directory, regardless of application. `JPATH_BASE` would be dependant on current application (site or administrator). `JPATH_SITE` is always for the site application.
See http://docs.joomla.org/Constants

Comment: Sorry for the waste of time. Turns out there was something wrong when I copied the code to check if the process was an update over to the postflight function